# Is a localization at a maximal ideal of a polynomial ring a perfect ring?

Tags: ring-theory, localization, projective-module, flatness, local-rings

There are several equivalent definitions for a perfect ring $R$ (not necessarily a commutative ring), for example: Every flat left $R$-module is projective;
see [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_ring).

Also, there is the notion of semiperfect rings, which include, for example, local rings.

> **Questions:** Is a regular local ring perfect? (probably no). At least, is a localization of a polynomial ring at a maximal ideal perfect?

For example, is $R=\mathbb{C}[x]_{(x)}$ perfect? Is $\mathbb{C}[x,y]_{(x,y)}$ perfect?

[Recall](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1943418/finitely-generated-and-flat-imply-projective) that finitely generated flat modules over an integral doamin are projective, though I am not sure if this result helps here.

Also see [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/32847/is-there-a-non-projective-flat-module-over-a-local-ring) relevant question.

Any hints and comments are welcome! Thank you.

Comment: "Is a regular local ring perfect" is a good question for the Database of Ring Theory, which yields [the following counterexamples.](https://ringtheory.herokuapp.com/search/results/?H=1&H=115&L=82l)  You'll notice that one of them is a polynomial ring localized at a maximal ideal, so that answers your second request too.

Comment: @rschwieb, thank you for the helpful reference!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to both question is "no" in a kind of extreme way.

A corollary of [Bass's Theorem $P$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_ring#Definitions) says that a commutative ring is perfect iff it satisfies the DCC on principal ideals.

A domain satisfying the DCC on principal ideals is already a field.

So it is not very fruitful idea to look for perfect rings among domains (in particular regular local rings or any polynomial ring over a field.)

Comment: Thank you very much! I was not familiar with Bass's Theorem, which surely makes my question not interesting.

Comment: @user237522 No problem! I felt like this was the most direct answer to your questions...

Comment: Indeed, this was the most direct answer to my question. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is 'no'. $\mathbb{C}[x]_{(x)}$ is a principal ideal domain (PID), even a discrete valuation ring (DVR). Over PIDs, we have

- flat $\iff$ torsionfree
- projective $\iff$ free

So it suffices to give an example of a torsionfree module which is not free. Just take the field of fractions (in case your PID is not a field itself).

Comment: Thank you very much! Please, are there localizations of $\mathbb{C}[x]$ or of $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$ which are perfect?

Comment: Yes, the zero ring. :-)

Comment: :-) Are there other examples?

Comment: (In your answer, we could not localize at $(0)$, since I wished to consider maximal ideals only, not just prime ideals).

Comment: Well, if $R$ is an integral domain, then $Q(R)$ is flat over $R$ (it's just a localization), but almost never projective, I suppose. At least when $R$ is a localization of some polynomial ring, I don't see when this could happen.

Comment: Thank you, so there is no hope to find perfect localizations among polynomial rings. Please, are there examples of integral domains with localizations at maximal ideals which are perfect?